# A good book for learning D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I saw `D3.js` and I was interested so I bought this [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025429.do)! I may be wrong,  however I found it un-fulfilling.

Does anyone have prime material for mastering `D3.js`for data visualization?

I can see a lot of potential for `D3.js`and I am very keen and interested.

thanks in advance!

**Update:**

I just completed reading [Interactive Data Visualization](http://web.archive.org/web/20160424170530/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/) for the Web by Scott Murray, great book! Try it, it's free.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

As @Autio already mentioned, there are the tutorials from Scott Murray on his [website](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/).

You will also note that on his site, he has a link to his recent d3 book, 
[Interactive Data Visualization for the Web](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026938.do).

However, that book is now available online for **free**, along with embedded jsbin examples.
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/index.html

So if you are looking for a "book", this would be a great start.

Another great place to start is the set of tutorials - you could almost think of them as a mini-book - found here:
http://www.dashingd3js.com/table-of-contents

Part of what is good about these two resources is that they should encourage you to immediately begin playing around with d3 in your browser; so you are actually using d3 and exploring how it works in simple cases, instead of only reading about how it works.

The d3 wiki on github has a good deal of tutorials, and is indispensable for getting a feel for not just d3 but what's going on in the d3 community,
yet I would probably recommend starting with the two links mentioned above, 
since they will provide a good base (with a sustained focus, 
as opposed to a one or two page post) for then jumping off 
into the other tutorials available.
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials

Also, consider what you want to end up doing with d3. By itself, d3 is really powerful yet fairly low-level, meaning: if you just need to make a bar chart instead of a NY Times election map of [512 paths to the White House](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/11/02/us/politics/paths-to-the-white-house.html?_r=0), then it may be worth looking at a tool like [vega](http://trifacta.github.io/vega/) that removes some of the low-level complexity that could otherwise be involved in creating an item such as a standard bar chart. And these tools are not few in number, as can be seen in this [gist listing libraries that make use of d3](https://gist.github.com/widged/6820559).

More recently, Nick Zhu, the author of [dc.js](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/) charting library that combines d3.js and crossfilter, came out with a new [Data Visualization with D3 Cookbook](http://nickqizhu.github.io/d3-cookbook/) that looks promising and appears to assume a bit more of the reader than does Scott Murray's book.

There's also a d3.js intro for people who are still new to HTML and CSS:
Part1: http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2014/11/getting-your-head-around-d3js.html
Part2: http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2014/12/getting-your-head-around-d3js-part2.html

Comment: I think mg1075s advice is good. Two other's I'd add would be the video series from @d3Vienno (https://www.youtube.com/user/d3Vienno) (I found them to be a great resource for learning from a different medium) and perhaps un-humbly [D3 Tips and Tricks](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks) as a pdf, epub or mobi or even fully on-line https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read :-)

Answer (score 8):

The book you mention is indeed a bit slim. Here are some tutorials I found useful in grasping D3: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3

Really the best method is to explore the source code of the examples hosted by Mike Bostock here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Answer (score 7):

I wrote some basic tutorials when I first started to learn, you can find them here:
https://bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-d3