# Javascript library for visualization of Lists (data structure)

Tags: data-structures, visualization, data-visualization, javascript

I need to create web page where user can choose a type of a list (linked, doubly linked, circular linked list etc.) and see how it looks like. User can add and remove elements from a list and see how list is changing.
Which library is better to use for visualization of List? It would be good to find library which can take a list as input param and return image or canvas. But If such library doesn't exists I need library which can draw rectangles with text inside and connect it with each other with lines.

[image]

Comment: Can you sketch a draw of what you want? I think what you're requesting is not that clear...

Comment: I wanted to do it when I was posting, but I am unavailable to do this because I just registered on this site and I need 10 points to do this, but I have only 6.

Comment: Upload it somewhere else and post a link to it.

Comment: With 6 points, he wouldn't be able to post a link either.

Comment: I received dome points and attached an image.
I'll try solution provided by @Jay Askren this or next week. But if someone can provide something else I can try it also.

Answer (score 1):

[D3.js](http://d3js.org/) is more than powerful enough to do what you want.  However, if all you want rectangles with in a list, you could use a table or divs for that.

**Edit:**
To figure out how to do this, I would recommend running through a tutorial on D3.  [Here are links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930748/a-good-book-for-learning-d3-js) to several.  There is a bit of a learning curve, but once you get over the learning curve, it is very nice.  As far as examples, what you want is similar to [this](http://nlpviz.bpodgursky.com/home)  or [this](https://github.com/nylen/d3-process-map) except your layout is much simpler.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript?rq=1) may also be helpful

Comment: There are many poweful examples on D3's example page, but I didn't found anything that is similar to my task. There are many beautiful things with diagrams, charts and graphics, but I just need to connect rectangles (with text inside) with arrows. Is there any example of how it can be implemented with D3.js?
*you could use a table or divs for that*
But how can I connect them with arrows?